# pypi does not update according to GitHub repository

Tags: python, git, pip, package, twine

I uploaded my project to PyPI for the first time last week. Then I revised some of my code and I changed the version number in setup.py. Then `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and `twine upload dist/*` like I did first time uploading the package. But somehow my content of my package is still the same. My program's menu is still from version 1.0.0 (currently 1.0.6).

My package is `pip install rsa-cipher`
The package repository is https://github.com/PizzaPat/RSA-Cipher

How can I synchronize my local files (or from GitHub repository) to my PyPI account?

P.S. The reason I have version 1.0.6 because I've been trying to figure out the way to update content

Comment: I see version 1.0.6 at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RSA-Cipher, and the content is ok, `setup.py` has `version='1.0.6'`. What's your problem?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Apparently I solved the problem. It was because of my directory name. My repository is RSA-Cipher, apparently '-' is not an identifier.